# How to remove unused "attributes" in Airflow docs?

Tags: attributes, airflow, markdown

Inside a BashOperator, I added a markdown snippet of documentation for the "Task Instance Details" of my Airflow nodes.
Now I can see my markdown, defined by the attribute "doc_md", but also

```
Attribute: bash_command
Attribute: doc
Attribute: doc_json
Attribute: doc_rst
Attribute: doc_yaml
```

I don't want to show any other attributes more than "doc_md", is it possible?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide some attribute from the table which is just below by adding them to `HIDE_ATTRS_FROM_UI`, but currently you cannot hide the attributes you have mentioned in your question.

Airflow defines them in [this method](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/airflow/www/utils.py#L541-L565) then it checks if the operators contains the attribute, and if yes, it adds it to the UI, and the attributes you want to hide are defined in the `BaseOperator` which is the parent of all the other operators.

A solution is creating a new operator by copy the code of `BaseOperator` without the fields you want to hide ([here](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/airflow/models/baseoperator.py#L872-L876)), then duplicating the code for the operators you are using and extending the new operator instead of `BaseOperator`, but I'm not sure if it's worth it.

Feel free to create an issue or open a pull request on Airflow to add a new option to hide these attributes.

Comment: Thank you @Hussein Awala, I opened an issue!